# WordPress - Overwriting/Filtering get_header_image_tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook

I want to change the output for get_header_image_tag function to output the exact HTML that I want to. I also want to be able to add data to the output such as new srcset that have not been covered...

I have tried to use [apply_filters get_header_image_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_header_image_tag/) to test it out but couldn't get it to work:

```
apply_filters('get_header_image_tag', "<img src>", get_custom_header(), ['url' => 'test']);
echo get_header_image_tag();
```

I am pretty convinced that my understanding of how the apply_filters works might be the issue there... I've been reading about it but I can't get my head around the parameters. Most of the examples I have found online used only a hook and a single value.

The way I understood it, I want the output to be `<img src=url>` by using the data in `get_custom_header()` and replacing the URL attribute with 'test'.

However, what is being outputted is the default get_header_image_tag. I've also tried to directly echo the apply_filters:

```
echo apply_filters('get_header_image_tag', "<img src>", get_custom_header(), ['url' => 'test']);
```

But then, only `<img src>` is outputted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are totally right, it is your understanding on how to use wordpress filters that is the issue :)

You are applying a filter when using [apply_filters()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/). To add your own filter to the [get_header_image_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_header_image_tag/) hook you have to use [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/). Here is an example on how adding a filter should look like:

```
// define the get_header_image_tag callback 
function filter_get_header_image_tag( $html, $header, $attr ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $html; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'get_header_image_tag', 'filter_get_header_image_tag', 10, 3 );
```

Here is an example on how you can control the full output of get_header_image_tag:

```
function header_image_markup($html, $header, $attr) {
    return '<figure><img src="'.$attr['src'].'" width="'.$attr['width'].'" height="'.$attr['height'].'" alt="'.$attr['alt'].'" srcset="'.$attr['srcset'].'" sizes="'.$attr['sizes'].'"></figure>';
}

add_filter('get_header_image_tag', 'header_image_markup', 20, 3);
```

But, what version of WP are you using? I'm pretty sure srcset is supported in the get_header_image_tag() as it appeared when I was using it just now.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out yesterday about the add_filter thing... Then some hours later, that it was actually overriding the output using the default parameters xD I am using the last version of WP always, however, while the srcset is supported, we want to control the output ourselves :)

I plan to read a lot more about add_filter, apply_filter, add_action and do_action ;)

Comment: @Dacramash Hahah, I know the feeling :) Action and filters are awesome! [Wordpress has 2000+ hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/) so there is a lot to play with :)